# MS SQL: ISNUMERIC wont work for variables used as string in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have observed an peculiar issue in the `ISNUMERIC` function. Below is the same code:

```
declare @variable nvarchar(max)  = '123,456,789,147,258,369'
if (ISNUMERIC(@variable) = 1 )
  select 'numeric' as output
else
  select 'char' as output`
```

Below is the link for demo of the out put and different scenarios
[Demo Here](http://rextester.com/ZEIE13288)

It gives output as Character, though it numeric. Any suggestions for the behavior.
I have observed this behavior only when we copy the numbers and paste it in variable declaration, instead if we just type the number then it works fine.

[Demo Here](http://rextester.com/TRP10908)

Comment: Without variable [Demo](http://rextester.com/CDY66071) still it isn't numeric.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` answers a question nobody has ever wanted to ask - "can this string be converted to *any* of the numeric datatypes, I *don't care* which one(s)".

Answer (score 1):

Your CSV string is just that, a string, despite that it consists of CSV numbers.  If you want to verify that you have an all-numeric CSV string you could try removing all commas and then asserting that what remains is a number:

```
declare @variable nvarchar(max) = '123,456,789,147,258,369'
if (ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(@variable, ',', ''l) = 1 )
select 'numeric' as output
else select 'char' as output
```

Comment: a negative like would be a better option here - you know exactly which characters you want to allow By continuing to use `ISNUMERIC` you leave yourself open to accepting e.g. `1d1` or `£`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The question of how to remove non numeric data on SQL Server is already well covered on Stack Overflow.  I only tried to offer an approach for the OP's specific data.

Comment: You yourself state "If you want to verify that you have an all-numeric CSV string" and then offer a solution that, because it's still using `ISNUMERIC`, doesn't in fact verify that fact.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever My take on the question was that the OP thought that since his CSV string represented numeric _data_ that `ISNUMERIC` should pick up on that.  Well, minus the separators and possibly some whitespace, `ISNUMERIC` might be able to answer that question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . Thanks. The solution worked with additional filtering on the NEXT line and SPACE character.

Answer (score 1):

The string you defined, '123,456,789,147,258,369' is not a number, a number cannot have multiple commas.

If you have specific criteria on what do you consider a number, your should build your a user defined function to determine to sort strings as 'numeric' or 'char' according to your criteria.

Best regards,
Sergio

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the behavior you are seeing appears to be due to the length of the string.

After reading this on MSDN:

> ISNUMERIC returns 1 when the input expression evaluates to a valid
>   numeric data type

I ran some tests:

```
select ISNUMERIC('1,234')
1
select ISNUMERIC('1,234,456')
1
```

proves that you can have commas in the string

```
select isnumeric('123,456,789,147,258,369')
0
```

confirms the behavior you are seeing.
  Your string is too big to be an int, but it could be a bigint, so:

```
select CONVERT(bigint,'123,456,789,147,258,369')
Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

select CONVERT(int,'1,234')
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,234' to data type int.
```

proves that strings with commas can't be converted to int.  What about decimals?

```
select CONVERT(decimal(10,0),'1,234')
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
select CONVERT(float,'1,234')
Error converting data type varchar to float.
```

nope.   that leaves money:

```
select CONVERT(money,'2,234')
2234.00
select CONVERT(money,'2,234,000')
2234000.00
```

so strings with (multiple) commas can be converted to money.   But if the number would be too big to fit in a money datatype:

```
select CONVERT(money,'123,456,789,147,258,369')
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type money.
```

then it can't be converted, and if it can't be converted, then ISNUMERIC()=0.

Comment: :-  
 Thanks for details analysis . This helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses .Below is the final solution I got by eliminating the comma, NEXT line char and Space character as below:

`declare @variable nvarchar(max) = '21386,  21385,  20178,  20176,  19958,  20026,  19976,  19933,  20029,  19921,  4552,   19784,  4700,   19730,  14655,  4749,   4998,   19604,'
if (ISNUMERIC(REPLACE( replace(REPLACE(REPLACE(@variable, ',' ,'1'), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(9), ''), CHAR(13), '')) = 1 )
select 'numeric' as output
else select 'char' as output`